# Odoo error when generating One2many field data

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Given the following class for the header:

```
class vontatas_head(models.Model):
    _name = 'vontatas.head'

    display_name = fields.Char(string="Sor", compute='_compute_display_name', store=False)
    plan_type_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='plan.type', string='Terv típus', required=True)
    year = fields.Integer(string='Év', required=True, default=lambda *a: strftime('%Y'))
    version = fields.Integer(string='Verzió', required=True, default=1)
    comment = fields.Char(string='Megjegyzés')
    vontatas_data_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='vontatas.data', inverse_name='vontatas_id', string='Adatok', default=get_default_lines)
```

And for the detail:

```
class vontatas_data(models.Model):
    _name = 'vontatas.data'

    vontatas_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="vontatas.head",  string="Vontatás sor")
    name = fields.Char(string="Megnevezés", required=True)
    code = fields.Char(string="Kód", required=True)
    type = fields.Selection([('total', 'Összesen'), ('input', 'Input')], string="Típus", default='input')
    value = fields.Float(string="Várható költség")
    parent_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="vontatas.data",  ondelete='cascade', string="Összesen sor")
    child_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name="vontatas.data", inverse_name='parent_id', string='Input sorok')
```

I have to automatically generate details data from a template with this code:

```
def get_default_lines(self):
    self.env.cr.execute("select name, code, type, parent_id from vontatas order by code")
    sorok = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    ids = []
    for sor in sorok:
        ids.append((0,0, { 'name': sor[0],
                           'code': sor[1],
                           'type': sor[2],
                           'parent_id': sor[3]
                           }))

    return ids
```

Everyting is working fine, but at the creation I have an error message: "One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing."

I know why this error is happening: at the moment of generation there is no valid parent_id.

My question is: how to provide any valid parent_id within the function get_default_lines, knowing that the data is actually just in memory, not stored yet in the database?
Or asked otherwise: How to keep the hierarchy level defined within the template?